# How to render .basis images?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

Basically I have javascript code that opens a .basis file and extracts the `UInt8Array` from it. This array is correct (it matches the `UInt8Array` of the same image when passed through the official transcoder). But how can I view it from the UInt8Array?

I tried converting to base64 but was unsuccessful.

```
async loadBasis(key, url, load) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.onload = async () => {
      const data = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
      const image = await this.basisFile(data);
      const width = image.getImageWidth(0, 0);
      const height = image.getImageHeight(0, 0);
      const images = image.getNumImages();
      const levels = image.getNumLevels(0);
      const has_alpha = image.getHasAlpha();

      const format = 10;
      const dstSize = image.getImageTranscodedSizeInBytes(0, 0, format);
      const dst = new Uint8Array(dstSize);

      if (!width || !height || !images || !levels) {
        console.warn("Invalid .basis file");
        image.close();
        image.delete();
        return;
      }

      if (!image.startTranscoding()) {
        console.warn("startTranscoding failed");
        image.close();
        image.delete();
        return;
      }

      if (!image.transcodeImage(dst, 0, 0, format, 0, 0)) {
        console.warn("image.transcodeImage failed");
        console.warn("transcodeImage failed");
        image.close();
        image.delete();
        return;
      }


    };
    xhr.send();

  }
```

Comment: Create a `<canvas>` element with the correct width and height, and then [set its image data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas) using your UInt8Array. Also, don't use the XMLHttpRequest method in modern JS, [use the `fetch()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).